# Xamarin forms fecha em Relase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, release

estou com um problema. minha aplicação funciona em debug porem, em release ela abre a splash screen e fecha apresentando um erro na tela: "aplicação parou"
abaixo esta o output application.
podem me ajudar?

> AndroidRuntime]   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>   [AndroidRuntime]  ... 3 more [Error] ERR:
>   exClass=android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable [Error] ERR:
>   exMsg=System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
>   [Error]   at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage..cctor () [0x00247] in
>   <41880298d32a47e6b90f5730cb0eb675>:0  [Error]    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- [Error]   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoField:GetValueInternal
>   (System.Reflection.MonoField,object) [Error]   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoField.GetValue (System.Object obj) [0x0005e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyConverter.ConvertFrom (System.Type type,
>   System.String propertyName, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineinfo)
>   [0x00057] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyConverter.Xamarin.Forms.IExtendedTypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString
>   (System.String value, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   [0x0015c] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object
>   value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] getConverter,
>   System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00034] in
>   <e53fc7074dab4ad8bba89c7f3e14cbfc>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object
>   value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever,
>   System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00021] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TrySetProperty
>   (System.Object element, System.String localName, System.Object value,
>   System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlServiceProvider serviceProvider,
>   System.Exception& exception) [0x00067] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue
>   (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName,
>   System.Object value, System.Object rootElement,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext
>   context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x00090] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00085] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00000] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00054] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00089] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.Visit
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x000b5] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00008] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00089] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00054] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode
>   rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext)
>   [0x00074] in :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String
>   xaml) [0x0005d] in :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type
>   callingType) [0x0002f] in :0 
>   [Error]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml
>   view, System.Type  [Error] ERR: file=MainActivity.java [Error] ERR:
>   class=md542a436044c1c4af0a9ebc2e2c58d67d3.MainActivity [Error] ERR:
>   method=n_onCreate line=-2 [Error] ERR:
>   stack=java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [Error]   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) [Error]
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [Error]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) [Error]    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>   [Error]   ... 1 more [Error] Caused by:
>   android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
>   [Error]   at FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage..cctor () [0x00247] in
>   <41880298d32a47e6b90f5730cb0eb675>:0  [Error]    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- [Error]   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoField:GetValueInternal
>   (System.Reflection.MonoField,object) [Error]   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoField.GetValue (System.Object obj) [0x0005e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyConverter.ConvertFrom (System.Type type,
>   System.String propertyName, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineinfo)
>   [0x00057] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyConverter.Xamarin.Forms.IExtendedTypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString
>   (System.String value, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   [0x0015c] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object
>   value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] getConverter,
>   System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00034] in
>   <e53fc7074dab4ad8bba89c7f3e14cbfc>:0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object
>   value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever,
>   System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00021] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TrySetProperty
>   (System.Object element, System.String localName, System.Object value,
>   System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlServiceProvider serviceProvider,
>   System.Exception& exception) [0x00067] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue
>   (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName,
>   System.Object value, System.Object rootElement,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext
>   context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x00090] in
>   :0  [Error]   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00085] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00000] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00054] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00089] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.Visit
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x000b5] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00008] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00089] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode
>   parentNode) [0x00054] in :0  [Error]
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode
>   rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext)
>   [0x00074] in [Error] ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 21516 [OneSignal]
>   Google Play services returned SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error. Current
>   retry count: 0 [OneSignal] java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
>   [OneSignal]   at
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zza(Unknown Source)
>   [OneSignal]   at
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown
>   Source) [OneSignal]   at
>   com.onesignal.PushRegistratorGPS$2.run(PushRegistratorGPS.java:151)
>   [OneSignal]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Comment: Veja [Esta resposta SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available). Possíveis causas `1 - Sem internet` | `2 - Horario errado`, etc. @otavio-alfenas

Comment: Ola @rubStackOverflow, obrigado por responder. incluir internet e permissões que utilizo no manifesto:


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.notinica" android:installLocation="auto">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Caso esteja complementando a pergunta, adicione estas informações editando sua pergunta.